# how to apply Json serialization or deserialization in request and response to HTTP method of rest api

Tags: java, json, rest, serialization

I am very new to Rest api in java .My Question is how to directly convert json string request to java class object before post or get function ,like

```
json string : '{"id":3,"name":name}'
```

rest api post method :

```
@Post
 public Something postData(Something obj) throws Exception {
}
```

so how to apply json serialization before request to this method.
right now i am converting it inside postData method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Jackson` API to play with JSON.
For the Following JSON data the Java object mapping can be done as follows.

```
    {
  "id": 123,
  "name": "Pankaj",
  "permanent": true,
  "address": {
    "street": "Albany Dr",
    "city": "San Jose",
    "zipcode": 95129
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    123456,
    987654
  ],
  "role": "Manager",
  "cities": [
    "Los Angeles",
    "New York"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "age": "29 years",
    "salary": "1000 USD"
  }
}

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.journaldev.jackson.model.Address;
import com.journaldev.jackson.model.Employee;


public class JacksonObjectMapperExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //read json file data to String
        byte[] jsonData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("employee.txt"));

        //create ObjectMapper instance
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        //convert json string to object
        Employee emp = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, Employee.class);

        System.out.println("Employee Object\n"+emp);

        //convert Object to json string
        Employee emp1 = createEmployee();
        //configure Object mapper for pretty print
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);

        //writing to console, can write to any output stream such as file
        StringWriter stringEmp = new StringWriter();
        objectMapper.writeValue(stringEmp, emp1);
        System.out.println("Employee JSON is\n"+stringEmp);
    }

    public static Employee createEmployee() {

        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.setId(100);
        emp.setName("David");
        emp.setPermanent(false);
        emp.setPhoneNumbers(new long[] { 123456, 987654 });
        emp.setRole("Manager");

        Address add = new Address();
        add.setCity("Bangalore");
        add.setStreet("BTM 1st Stage");
        add.setZipcode(560100);
        emp.setAddress(add);

        List<String> cities = new ArrayList<String>();
        cities.add("Los Angeles");
        cities.add("New York");
        emp.setCities(cities);

        Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
        props.put("salary", "1000 Rs");
        props.put("age", "28 years");
        emp.setProperties(props);

        return emp;
    }

}
```

Source : http://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-processing-api-in-java-example-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or do a manually serialization/deserialization using [JSONObject/JSONArray](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/) classes ([example here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm)). There are many other ways/libs to do this.

Comment: yes , i am able to convert it inside the post or get function .I have seen some code where its getting converted before request to post method i dont remember about it.